# Debug a Javascript issue properly? (most likely client-side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multidimensional-array, websocket, socket.io

This issue is most likely client-side, but I'm not sure about that. This is about an auction website and I get data (price, time left) every second with a WebSocket (node.js Server).

If the price changes, my script automatically fires an event where the countdown and price of this auction flashes and my array `timers` gets refreshed with the seconds left (`auction.duration`):

```
if ($('.price' + timers[i][0]).data('curr_text') !== $('.price' + timers[i][0]).text()) 
{
$(".flashing" + timers[i][0]).toggle("highlight").toggle("highlight");
timers[i][1] = auction.duration;        
}
```

So, I was afk some hours and some of the auction timers went to zero (shows up like this `00:00:00`), but not all timers. As I refreshed the page, these auctions were still running, so this is most likely a client-side JavaScript problem. And also a huge problem, because a user thinks the auction is over, refreshes the page and will notice that it's actually still running.

I can just guess that this issue occurs, because of some timing issues, but I'm not sure. Also I don't know how to debug this issue, because I can't stare on the screen for hours to wait for this to happen. So I would appreciate suggestions to debug this.

I think it's also helpful to show you my full code and maybe you see something that I'm missing:

```
// prevent flashing after page loaded
$(".refresh-item").each(function() {
$this = $(this);
var id = $this.attr("data-id"); 
$('.price' + $this.attr("data-id")).data('curr_text', $('.price' + id).text());
});
// format timer
var formatSeconds = function(secs){
    var pad = function(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
    };
    var h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor((secs / 3600) % 1 * 60); // Reminder of an hour of seconds x 60
    var s = Math.floor((secs / 60) % 1 * 60); // Reminder of a minute of seconds x 60
    return pad(h) +":"+ pad(m) +":"+ pad(s);
};  

var timers = [];
var socket = io.connect('http://xxx.rhcloud.com:8000/',{'forceNew':true });
socket.on('stream', function (data) {
    $.each(data.streamArray,function(index,auction){    
    duration = auction.duration;
    num_rows = data.streamArray.length;

    if (duration > 0)
    {
    var price_retail = $("#" + auction.id).attr("data-retail"); 

    var calc = auction.price.toFixed(2);
    var price_calc = calc.toString().replace(/\./g, ',');   
    $(".price" + auction.id).html(price_calc + "€");            
    $(".discount" + auction.id).html(discount + "%");

    if (timers.length < num_rows)
    timers.push([auction.id, auction.duration]);
    for(i in timers) 
    {                   
        if ($('.price' + timers[i][0]).data('curr_text') !== $('.price' + timers[i][0]).text()) 
        {
        $(".flashing" + timers[i][0]).toggle("highlight").toggle("highlight");
        timers[i][1] = auction.duration;        
        }
    }   
    $('.price' + auction.id).data('curr_text', $('.price' + auction.id).text());        
    } 
    else
    {
    $(".sold" + auction.id).html("<div class='sold'>SOLD</div>").fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast');            
    }
    });
});
function timerCount() {
    for(i in timers) {              
        if(timers[i][1] <= 0) {
        delete timers[i]; // if timer seconds is less than 1, delete it.
        } else {            
        timers[i][1]--; // else, decrease it by 1 second.
        duration_html = formatSeconds(timers[i][1]);        
        $(".duration" + timers[i][0]).html(duration_html);              
        }   
    }
}
setInterval(timerCount, 1000);
```

**It's also important to mention that a red sign called "SOLD" will appear if an auction is actually over (see end of socket stream). But this also didn't happen. The timer just stopped and went to `00:00:00`. So it has to do something with the array that `delete timers[i]` was triggered too soon, I guess?**

Additional information:
I forgot to mention that these timers reset to approx. 15-16 seconds every time a user placed a bid. So the array `timers` is alive for a long time. And this array loops every single second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your timers got deleted every 1 minute by this code:

```
function timerCount() {
    for(i in timers) {              
        if(timers[i][1] <= 0) {
            delete timers[i]; // if timer seconds is less than 1, delete it.
        } else {            
            timers[i][1]--; // else, decrease it by 1 second.
            duration_html = formatSeconds(timers[i][1]);        
            $(".duration" + timers[i][0]).html(duration_html);              
        }   
    }
}
```

Where are you decreasing minutes and hours?

And the second thing - you cannot guarantee that time on client and server is synchronized so you should perform some AJAX requests for time in timers and adjust your timers with some interval.

Comment: No. Maybe I forgot to mention that these timers reset to 15 seconds every time a user placed a bid. So these array are alive for a long time. And this array loops every single second. At the top is a function to convert into the `hh:mm:ss` format regarding your question. Also I experienced laggy timers when I just display the data received and don't do it client-side. The first code in my post is the part where I assign the "new" duration/time left.

Comment: What does `%1` part do then? It is always `0` doesn't it?